# Find service by network activity

Tags: networking, monitoring, services

I see a strange DNS request at tcpdump and I want to find service which is originated from. I've already tried to find it with different monitoring tools but still no luck. Is there any proven solution?

**UPD**: I find "-k NP" switch for `tcpdump` on Mac, it is showing log like:

```
13:09:41.589264 (proc Skype:182) IP 192.168.xx.xx.33576 > 157.55.xx.xx.40034: UDP, length 35
13:09:41.674938 (proc Skype:182) IP 213.199.xx.xx.40003 > 192.168.xx.x.33576: UDP, length 20
```

I need the same for Debian.

Comment: The DNS traffic you see is usually encapsulated in UDP, encapsulated in IP. In the IP header you will find a *source address*, which enables you to identify from which computer the traffic originates. In the UDP header you will find a *source port* which can be used on the originating computer to identify the originating process, for instance using `netstat`.

Comment: Unfortunately `netstat` can't showing sessions in real-time. DNS request lasts only few milliseconds. So it is very hard to find service by source port with `netstat`.

Comment: It's a successful lookup then. What's so strange about it? You could introduce an  [artificial delay](http://serverfault.com/q/506072/125845) so that netstat works. Other than that you could watch for longer lasting connections to the answer of the strange request. Every tool has the timing problem and the `pcap` based tools [apparently can't do what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24050358/1129682). Maybe the kernel has some on_socket_open notification, but I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SystemTap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap). It should enable you to list all the process creating DNS sockets and dump the connection information to the console.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [it is always preferred](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  You can improve this post by showing how to use SystemTap to solve the problem.